# Selenium - start your normal chrome and not chromium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

im looking example how can i start my normal google chrome in webdriver c#?

For now i use :

```
ChromeDriver driver;
public ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService;
    
chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService,chromeOptions);
```

But it run my chromedriver.exe installed inside project. Can i just run my simple installed chrome? Without download any chromedriver.exe?  It's important for me , because some website check if there is opened chromium with chromedriver.exe.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want not just open it but also perform some interaction with your site then you have to deal with Selenium and WebDriver.

You can try `Python` and [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) which has some workarounds preventing some systems to detect that your browser is running under webdriver control.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's the chromedriver.exe that lets you interact with Chrome so, without the driver, you wouldn't be able to interact with the actual browser.

If your issue is with chromium, try driving Mozilla with [GeckoDriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium always uses chromedriver.exe for interacting with Chrome, I think you mean you want to load your **default data directory**. You can add a chrome option for this purpose:

```
chromeOptions.AddArguments(@"C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
```

**Take care, any other chrome must not be running that time with the same data directory. Like you may have run for your personal use.**

You can also create a data directory somewhere else if you just want to show some realistic behavior to a website. But some websites are smart enough so it does not work every time.